# Comma placement between two auxiliary verbs

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> In fact the course **I did wasn’t** even a pure photography one; it was one area of optional specialism within an overall Graphic Design degree course. [A SUNDAY IN TEIGNMOUTH 1986](http://www.nadolski.com/teignmouth.html)

In this case, Is it better to add *comma ( , )* or *it* to avoid put two auxiliary verbs after each other? or Is it Okay to keep it like this?

Comment: Commas are generally a matter of style... that one particularly so. I'd be happier to argue that there should most definitely be a comma after "in fact" than anywhere else.

Comment: I'd go one step further than @Catija and argue that a comma should **not** be where you are considering adding one.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why you think that there should be a comma here? What resource told you that this was necessary?

Comment: I think adding two auxiliary verbs after each other is incorrect grammatically.

Comment: Even if it was incorrect grammatically (and it isn't), adding a comma wouldn't make it correct.

Comment: @Shannak Using auxiliary *did* and a modal auxiliary, or using two modal auxiliaries together, is indeed ungrammatical--***when they are part of the same verb phrase***. So you are quite right in that respect. However, as snailplane's answer explains, these auxiliaries are in different verb phrases in your example. *Did* is in a verb phrase inside the Subject, whereas *can* is the head of the verb phrase forming the Predicate.

Comment: **did** is not an auxiliary verb there but a lexical verb ( "the course I took" or "the course I completed")  and **I did** is a fused relative clause.

Comment: @TRomano Oops. Yes, *did* is a lexical verb there. That's a bare relative clause there (not a fused one, though) :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comma you're asking about appears between a subject (*the course I did*) and the verb that predicates on it (*wasn't*).  Most of the time, you shouldn't put a comma in this position.

On page 1730 of *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Geoffrey Nunberg points out that we do find commas in this position once in a while, usually when it's necessary to prevent the sentence from being misread:

> Most of those who can, work at home.

Without the comma, most people will read the sentence incorrectly.  They'll get to the end of the sentence thinking *who can work at home* is a relative clause, and then they'll have to go back and re-read it once they figure out *work at home* is intended to predicate on *most of those who can*.  Using a comma (quite exceptionally!) can help with this problem.

In your example, a misreading is impossible:

> The course I did wasn’t even a pure photography one.

It's impossible for *did* and *wasn't* to combine this way, so we can tell that there's a boundary between them without a comma.  *The course I did* must be a subject, while *wasn't* is the verb that begins the following predicate.

There is no justification for an exception here, so you should not add a comma in that position.

---

As an aside, you could optionally add a comma after the initial adjunct *in fact*:

> In fact, the course I did wasn’t even a pure photography one; it was one area of optional specialism within an overall Graphic Design degree course.

But this sort of comma is purely a matter of style, and the author's choice to leave this comma out is perfectly fine.

Comment: +1 Thank goodness someone answered this very good question!